# JavaScript not working in IE, .data? setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've developed the following code which simply swaps one image for another every x-seconds.  All works fine and returns no errors in Chrome.  However, in IE (latest back to IE8) it simply does nothing, returns no errors, just stays on the first image.

Any advice?  I remember reading somewhere that setInterval can cause issues in IE.

Consider:

```
$(function () {
    var fElement = $('.fadein');
    fElement.find('img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        if (!fElement.data('paused')) {
            fElement.find(':first-child')
                .stop(true, true) // fixes le tabbed/hidden animation queue
                .fadeOut()
                .next('img')
                .fadeIn()
                .end()
                .appendTo('.fadein');
        } else {
            console.log('waiting...');
        }
    }, 2000);
    $('map').hover(
        function () {
            console.log('pausing');
            fElement.data('paused', 1);
        },
        function () {
            console.log('unpausing');
            fElement.data('paused', 0);
        }
    );
});
if (!console && !console.log) {
    console = {};
    console.log = function () {};
}
```

and the CSS:

```
.fadein {
display: block;
height: 49px;
width: 287px;
float: left;
}
.fadein img {
position:absolute;
}
.stripContainer {
display:block;
height: 49px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="fadein">
    <img src="img1.jpg" border="0" width="287" height="49" alt="" style="" id="level2Menu"/>
    <img src="img2.jpg" border="0" width="287" height="49" alt="" style="" id="level2Menu"/>
</div>
<div class="stripContainer">
    <img src="img3.jpg" usemap="#secondM" border="0" width="385" height="49" alt="" style="float:left;" id="level2Menu"/>
    <img src="img4.jpg" usemap="#secondM" border="0" width="288" height="49" alt="" style="float:right;" id="level2Menu"/>
</div>
```

EDIT:  This fiddle shows it working AS IT SHOULD in Chrome:  http://jsfiddle.net/8f5uU/

Comment: You might get more help if you think of a real title for the question.

Comment: jQuery 2.X versions don't support IE<9.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I have no idea what to call this question, I've tried console.log'ing and I can't find what the issue is..  It's literally an IE/JS issue.

Comment: @Teemu this isn't working in ANY version of IE.  8-11 tested.

Comment: Does "pausing/unpausing" displays?

Comment: Is this correct: `... src="img3.jpg" ... alt="float:left;" style=""`? Also `id`s should be unique, or these are just in the post, not found in the production code?

Comment: Yes, when hovering on and off the image, console logs of pausing and unpausing can be seen.  Console logs work at any stage of the script, except after the else.  So the problem is in the line with element.find and fadeout/in.
@Teemu, the HTML isn't important right now - I didn't use the real HTML and it's sensitive info.  I just whipped those up as an example.  Any syntax errors wont be in the original markup.

Comment: Ohh I know what you mean, the float being under the alt haha.  Cheers for the spot (this WAS in the original markup, but didn't fix the problem).

Comment: Have you tried Firefox, Safari, Opera?

Comment: the fiddle works fine in IE10.

Comment: `!console && !console.log` may produce an error along the lines of `method "log" does not exist`.

Comment: Fiddle works also in IE11. @Jazza If there were a problem with `&& console.log`, there would also be an error...

Comment: Yeah it's console logging, without errors.  I haven't tried FF, Safari or Opera.  I do the majority of my work in Chrome then test afterwards starting with the worst (IE).

Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend testing in Firefox, Safari and Opera. That way you'll know for sure it's IE screwing up, or it's actually Chrome (which happens).

Comment: Will do.  Least I can rely on FF console/errors more than I can IE!

Cheers for help so far lads.

Comment: No worries. I've had my fair share of IE issues. Sadly though, the other browsers have issues of their own! Only today I was dealing with a Safari-specific issue that every other browser seemed to handle fine (even IE).

Comment: You want to put "break points" in your code - logs to the console after every logic check or in every loop. It'll help you debug your code.

Comment: Works in IE11 as it does in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, setInterval should not cause any problems in earlier version of IE. However, jQuery might. As specified in the [jQuery Doc:](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)

> Edge: (Current - 1) and Current
>
> Firefox: (Current - 1) and Current
>
> Internet Explorer: 9+

And it goes on to say:

> If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use [jQuery 1.12](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/#jquery-all-1.x).

Try using an older version of jQuery and see how it goes.